# Why did Han Solo's blaster shot bounce off the garbage compactor's walls?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

After rescuing Leia from the Empire, Luke, and Han Solo are trapped in a garbage compactor. Han tries to blast the door but his blaster shot bounces off many times:

[image: animated GIF of the scene described above]

Why did Han Solo's blaster shot bounce so many times in this scene?

Comment: "I already tried it. It’s magnetically sealed!"  And since blaster shots are magnetically contained plasma (or something like that) it bounced.

Comment: Technically, they're in the garbage _masher_ at this point, not the chute (which is what lead them to it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The script indicates that the doors and wall are metal**. This is, apparently, something that will reflect a blaster bolt at a short distance.

> Han draws his laser pistol and fires at the hatch. **The
> laserbolt ricochets wildly around the small metal room.**
> Everyone dives for cover in the garbage as the bolt explodes
> almost on top of them. Leia climbs out of the garbage with a
> rather grim look on her face.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: A New Hope - Original Screenplay](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-A-New-Hope.html)</sup></sub>

The junior novelisation, on the other hand, notes that **the door and wall are *magnetically sealed*, and thus blaster-reflective.** Quite how one magnetically seals a ***wall*** isn't described in any detail (and frankly seem to be a typo/misunderstanding on the part of the novelisation author) but there you go.

> Too late. Han fired at the hatch, and **the laserbolt ricocheted wildly
> around the metal-walled chamber**. Everyone dived for cover until the
> fired bolt’s charge ended in a small explosion that didn’t even dent
> the metal wall.
>
> ...
>
> Chewbacca turned to a wall and cowered. Despite the hazard posed by the **magnetically sealed walls,** Luke and Han held their blasters out, ready to fire. Han said, “It’s worse.”
>
> <sub><sup>[A New Hope: Junior Novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_IV:_A_New_Hope_(junior_novelization))</sup></sub>

Answer (score 13):

As Luke said to Han, it's **the magnetic seal** also called a **vacuum seal**. It is a technology that used electromagnetic fields to lock metal parts together. Although not quite explained in the movie it implies that Luke, Leia and Chewie have already gone through that near-death experience, Han subjected them to it all over again. That wasn't shown in the movie to keep the narrative and *to emphasize* on Han being a hot-head who doesn't answer to anyone.

That technology appeared in many Star Wars games like **Star Wars: Edge of the Empire** and many other RPG games.

Comment: A vacuum seal is a real thing.  A magnetic seal is not.

Comment: @Buzz ....from a certain point of view a magnetic seal is real thing ;) https://www.grainger.com/product/45LW89

Comment: @NKCampbell I thought about adding that caveat, but that’s not the kind of magnetic seal that applies to the *Star Wars* trash compactor.